# How to FTP a file from an Android Gradle build?

Tags: android, ftp, gradle

I'm trying to FTP the signed APK after a Gradle build. I've already added the new build config that will sign the APK, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to invoke an FTP task.

I found an official looking sample at [section 59.6](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html), however it complains that it cannot resolve dependency org.apache.ant:ant-commons-net:1.8.4. So apparently I'm missing something obvious here, like where to put a given jar file or reference it, although I thought maven would handle this sort of thing?

For reference, here is the linked sample which fails with a message about the dependency:

```
configurations {
    ftpAntTask
}

dependencies {
    ftpAntTask("org.apache.ant:ant-commons-net:1.8.4") {
        module("commons-net:commons-net:1.4.1") {
            dependencies "oro:oro:2.0.8:jar"
        }
    }
}

task ftp << {
    ant {
        taskdef(name: 'ftp',
                classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP',
                classpath: configurations.ftpAntTask.asPath)
        ftp(server: "ftp.apache.org", userid: "anonymous", password: "me@myorg.com") {
            fileset(dir: "htdocs/manual")
        }
    }
}
```

This fails with the message:

```
> Could not find org.apache.ant:ant-commons-net:1.8.4.
```

Here is my complete gradle.build file, with some sensitive information removed:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    signingConfigs {
        signed {
            storeFile file("(removed)")
            storePassword "(removed)"
            keyAlias "(removed)"
            keyPassword "(removed)"
        }
     }

    buildTypes {
        signed {
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.signed
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    ftpAntTask
}

dependencies {
    ftpAntTask("org.apache.ant:ant-commons-net:1.8.4") {
        module("commons-net:commons-net:1.4.1") {
            dependencies "oro:oro:2.0.8:jar"
        }
    }
}

task ftp << {
    ant {
        taskdef(name: 'ftp',
                classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP',
                classpath: configurations.ftpAntTask.asPath)
        ftp(server: "(removed)", userid: "(removed)", password: "(removed)", remoteDir: "(removed)") {
            fileset(dir: "(removed)") {
                include(name: "(removed)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havn't declared a repository that can be used to resolve the declared artifacts. Try adding the following snippet to your build.gradle file:

```
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}
```

cheers,

René

Comment: Thanks, but, I do have that in my build file. I updated my question.

Comment: No, you just declared a repository for your gradle plugins (the repository block in the buildscript section) you need another one on toplevel as I've done it in my snippet. There are plans to make in easier to apply plugins in the future and make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the native ant get task which supports FTP, works with no outside dependencies:

```
  ant {
    get(src: "ftp://<hostname>/remote/path/to/file.jar", dest: "/local/path/to/file", username: 'anonymous', password: 'anonymous')
  }
```

Comment: is there a similar way for the reverse direction? I want to upload a file to a ftp server...

Comment: @Rosso Sure just use ant { put(...) } instead of get