# How to upload folder contents to FTP server using Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am new to gradle and I don't know how to upload my /bin folder contents to the FTP server. Tried to find solution in internet, but they didn't help to me.

My build.gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.dom4j.dom4j:1.6.1'
    compile 'jaxen:jaxen:1.1.4'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

build.doLast {
    copy {
        into 'bin'
        from 'build/libs'
    }
}
```

Now I want to write task which will upload /bin folder contents to the FTP server.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

ftpAntTask is fairly simple to use.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    ftpAntTask
}

dependencies {
    ftpAntTask("org.apache.ant:ant-commons-net:1.8.4") {
        module("commons-net:commons-net:1.4.1") {
            dependencies "oro:oro:2.0.8:jar"
        }
    }
}

task ftp << {
    ant {
        taskdef(name: 'ftp',
                classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP',
                classpath: configurations.ftpAntTask.asPath)
        ftp(server: "(removed)", userid: "(removed)", password: "(removed)", remoteDir: "(removed)") {
            fileset(dir: "(removed)") {
                include(name: "(removed)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(This example was made from [How to FTP a file from an Android Gradle build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201815/how-to-ftp-a-file-from-an-android-gradle-build))

Answer (score 3):

Use [apache commons net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library. There's an [example](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.java) of `FTPClient` usage.

You also need to configure dependencies for the build script itself. Following code does it:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    }
}

task upload << {
     def ftp = new FTPClient()
     //following logic..
}
```

Comment: The example is 480 lines... can it be done in under 10?

Comment: @Noumenon Most of that example is just.... a very elaborative example, seems more like a real program to me with usage instructions, parameter handling and stuff. Maybe 10 lines is too little, but it is probably possible with less than 30.