# Use netbeans to deploy gradle war into Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, gradle, war

I am looking at NetBeans to determine if I want to use it for my ide.  My project is a simple Spring-based war build using Gradle. My target app server is Tomcat 8.

I was able to import my Gradle project into NetBeans, and launch the Gradle build to yield a war from the project navigator. I have set up my Tomcat server as a server within NetBeans, but I don't see any indication that NetBeans understands that I have a war project or any means to deploy/debug that war into my Tomcat server.

Obviously, I can do the deploy manually or through Gradle plugins and then attach the NetBeans debugger to Tomcat remotely, but my goal is the have NetBeans manage the build, deploy, debug natively if possible.

Any pointers towards docs on this scenario would be helpful as my googling efforts haven't turned anything up.

Answer (score 0):

see [Artifact Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html); this means, you would need an "upload task", which would need to "finalize" the last one build task. this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054752/how-to-upload-folder-contents-to-ftp-server-using-gradle) would provide two suitable examples (also works with NetBeans).