# Gradle ant ftp error: "425 Connection timed out"

Tags: gradle, ant, upload, ftp

I have a problem with my gradle build script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

/*
 * Sources:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/q/17201815/4490015
 * https://github.com/Vazkii/Botania/blob/master/build.gradle
 */

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    ftpAntTask
}

/*
 * Load configuration file.
 */
ext.priv = parseConfig(file('private.properties'))

/*
 * Some project properties
 */
version = '0.0.1'
group = 'randers.notenoughvocab'
archivesBaseName = 'NotEnoughVocab'

dependencies {
    ftpAntTask('org.apache.ant:ant-commons-net:1.8.4') {
        module('commons-net:commons-net:1.4.1') {
            dependencies 'oro:oro:2.0.8:jar'
        }
    }
}

void ftp(Map args, Closure antFileset = {}) {
    ant {
        taskdef(name: 'ftp',
                classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP',
                classpath: configurations.ftpAntTask.asPath)
        Map ftpArgs = args + [ //some default options
                               verbose : 'yes',
                               server  : priv.host,
                               userid  : priv.user,
                               password: priv.pass
        ]
        delegate.ftp(ftpArgs) {
            antFileset.delegate = delegate
            antFileset()
        }
    }
}

def parseConfig(File config) {
    config.withReader {
        def prop = new Properties()
        prop.load(it)
        return (new ConfigSlurper().parse(prop))
    }
}

/**
 * Uploads the javadoc to the server specified in private.properties
 */
task('uploadJavadoc', dependsOn: 'javadoc') << {
    ftp(action: 'send') {
        fileset(dir: 'build/docs/javadoc')
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'randers.notenoughvocab.main.NotEnoughVocab'
    }
}

task('prepareBuild') {
    ant.replace(file: 'src/main/java/randers/notenoughvocab/main/Reference.java', token: '@VERSION@', value: version)
}

build.dependsOn(tasks.prepareBuild)
```

I get the following error message:

> could not put file: 425 Could not open data connection to port 55080: Connection timed out

Apparently it works [for others](https://github.com/Vazkii/Botania/blob/e1e7fd4c89ddd8bebf89f7ecd6a37ab83ffd4210/build.gradle#L153-L167).
The server I specified in `private.properties` works fine with a FTP client like FileZilla, I do not time out. I have also tried the same with a local FTP server, but since the transport has no bandwith limitation, the transport was instant.
What can I do to prevent the timeout? And is the port `55080` something I should be concerned about?

I also did some debugging earlier and I ensured the `priv.host`, `priv.user` and `priv.pass` variables contained the correct information.

Comment: Did you try with passive mode? Pass `passive: 'yes'` (or maybe `passive: true`) to the ftp args

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that error occurs when you launch your program from your home computer, which is usually NAT'ed and does not have a publicly routable IP, you may try to use FTP passive mode. From the [Ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html) documentation you should simply add `passive: 'yes'` to your `ftpArgs`.

FTP is such a weird protocol: for downloading and uploading files another connection is opened **by the server to the client** and this usually cause headeaches to home users, who do not have public IPs. The simple solution is  called "passive mode"